# Angular-CLI proxy won't connect through Docker (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, proxy

I am running Docker on Windows through WSL.

I am trying to proxy requests from my client app running on port 4200, to my backend running on the same domain on port 80. However, when it tries this, I am getting the following error in the logs:

```
[HPM] GET /api/test -> http://mysite.local/api/
client_1    | [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/test from mysite.local:4200 to http://mysite.local/api/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I can access `http://mysite.local/api/` directly without a problem. Only the proxy from `:4200` seems to fail.

I have an Angular application docker container, an nginx container which serves the PHP API, and a php-fpm container for the PHP API.

All are running through docker compose.

Here is all the relevant code and configuration.

**Windows host entry**

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.local
```

**URLs**

- Angular app runs on `http://mysite.local:4200`
- Backend API runs on `http://mysite.local`
- Using the proxy.conf.json, the Angular app forwards `http://mysite.local:4200/api/*` to `http://mysite.local/api`

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api/*" : {
        "target" : "http://mysite.local/api",
        "secure" : false,
        "logLevel" : "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

**Angular ng serve command via `npm run start`**

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --poll 1 --disableHostCheck
```

`--host` has to be `0.0.0.0` for the Angular application to be accessible.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  client:
    image: angular-cli:1.1
    volumes:
      - ./src/client:/var/www
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    command: >
      bash -c "cd /var/www && npm run start"

  api:
    image: laravel-app:1.5
    volumes:
      - ./src/server:/var/www
      - ./opcache.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini
      - ./xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
      - "DB_DATABASE=..."
      - "DB_USERNAME=..."
      - "DB_PASSWORD=..."
    depends_on:
        - database
        - web
    working_dir: /var/www

  web:
    image: nginx:1.10
    volumes:
      - ./src/server:/var/www
      - ./vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7.28
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=mysite"
      - "MYSQL_USER=..."
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=..."
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=..."
    ports:
        - 33061:3306
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

**Docker images**

None of the docker images used in the docker-compose file expose any ports. All port mapping is done through the docker-compose file itself.

**nginx vhost.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    server_name mysite.local www.mysite.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is (e.g. is it the proxy configuration, nginx configuration, or docker configuration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I figured out my problem.

I forgot that the Angular application is running *inside* of the Docker network. This means the host I want to proxy to isn't `http://mysite.local`, but rather the name of the service defined in the docker-compose file.

In this case, that host is `web` (which you can see if you look at the docker-compose file I posted in my question above).

Thus to make this work, I had to make my `proxy.conf.json` file look like this:

```
{
    "/api" : {
        "target" : {
            "host": "web",
            "port": 80,
            "protocol": "http:"
        },
        "secure" : false,
        "logLevel" : "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Note how `host` is set to `web`. This is what allows it to reference the `web` host/service defined in the docker network by the docker-compose file.

If you look at the database environment variables for the `api` service, you'll see a similar thing was done to reference the `database` host in the docker network. That same concept had to apply here, to the proxy.

Comment: this is not working.